# join table not posting in

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have 3 tables doc_list, cat_list and cat_doc_link_table I have built an admin panel with a WYSIWYG post creator and the idea is when you want to create a new post i lists out the categories you can assign it to like so:

```
<?php
require_once '../../db_con.php'; 

try{
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cat_list");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$category = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist" >
    <?php
        foreach($category as $cat){ 
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"]; ?>" name="cat_no[]" id="box1"> <?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Then there is the the rest of the input fields.

It will post in the doc_list and add a new row as expected but in the join table where I expect it to take the value of the doc and the value of the cat and marry them up it just will not post into that table - I have done a var dump and it certainly knows which categories I am selecting from the checkboxes but will just not post into that join table?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cat_doc_link_table`(`link_cat_id`, `link_doc_id`) VALUES";
$values = "";
$params = [];

foreach($_POST["cat_no"] as $cat)

    var_dump($cat);

{
    $values.= "(?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $cat["cat_id"];
    $params[] = $docId;
}
    $values = substr($values, 0, -2);
    $sql.= $values;
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);       

    if ($dbh->query($sql)) {

    }else{}

    $dbh = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e)

    {
    header ('Location: ../list_doc.php?success=1');
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access selected category you should use just $cat, not $cat["cat_id"]

```
...
foreach($_POST["cat_no"] as $cat)

{
    var_dump($cat); // 

    $values.= "(?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $cat; // correct here
    $params[] = $docId;
}
...
```

Comment: Jeez how did I not spot that